# Twilio-Python RequestValidator fails for incoming MMS but works for sms

Tags: python, twilio, mms

I'm using the Twilio-Python library (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python).

In particular, I'm using RequestValidator to validate requests to my endpoint from Twilio.

I've rigged a webhook to Twilio phone numbers, so that when a number receives a sms or mms, it posts to my endpoint.

It works perfectly fine for sms. However, it doesn't work for MMS. Because the signature is a hash, I can't figure out what's wrong with the inputs I'm passing to the RequestValidator.

In fact, I tested creating twilio signatures manually using python's interactive console. I was able to generate the correct signatures for SMS but not MMS, using the param dictionaries I generated.

Below is a string representation of the param dictionary for an MMS:

> {u'FromZip': u'94025', u'From': '+16507049058', u'SmsMessageSid':
>   u'MM08a68b296dd8050ff4fdb608627714ec', u'FromCity': u'PALO ALTO',
>   u'ApiVersion': u'2010-04-01', u'To': '+16195672786', u'MediaUrl0':
>   'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd0edc68c0b0bf1b330b9680461a4406a/Messages/MM08a68b296dd8050ff4fdb608627714ec/Media/ME00796c012d82cbce5fae813f68be2ca3',
>   u'NumSegments': u'1', u'MediaContentType0': 'image/png',
>   u'AccountSid': u'ACd0edc68c0b0bf1b330b9680461a4406a', u'SmsSid':
>   u'MM08a68b296dd8050ff4fdb608627714ec', u'ToCity': u'SAN DIEGO',
>   u'FromState': u'CA', u'ToState': u'CA', u'MessageSid':
>   u'MM08a68b296dd8050ff4fdb608627714ec', u'SmsStatus': u'received',
>   u'FromCountry': u'US', u'ToZip': u'92108', u'ToCountry': u'US',
>   u'NumMedia': u'1'}

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to validate the requests?